# Using bash environment from an external OS partition

Tags: shell, chroot

I have an external partition, `/dev/sda`, which contains an Ubuntu OS. The root is located in `/dev/sda2`.

I would like to access commands from this OS partition.

I have tried doing the following steps:

I first boot from a Linux usb stick (Arch Linux actually).
Then I mount the target partition in the `/mnt` folder of my installation image:

```
$ mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

I used chroot to set the root folder:

```
$ chroot /mnt
```

But I get the following error:

```
chroot: failed to run command `/usr/bin/zsh` : No such file or directory
```

What is going on? 
Maybe I was mislead by the man page of chroot :

`chroot - run command or interactive shell with special root directory`

Am I using the right approach in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't specify what you wanted to run inside the chroot. So it tries to start a shell. It also doesn't know which shell it should start, so it tries to use the one from the `$SHELL` environment variable, which is apparently `/usr/bin/zsh`. This shell apparently does not exist inside your chroot.

Tell `chroot` what you want to run:

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might also have other issues unless you `mount -o bind` several things from the host, such as `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/sys`, & `/proc`.

Comment: Thanks I did not understand how it worked. So now it is ok, I can for instance call the command `html2text` which I personally installed. However when I use the `ls` command or any other in `/bin`, it tells me `The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable` and I can use it typing `/bin/ls`. Should I use `export /bin`? I wonder why the path to `html2text` would already be in the PATH environment.